# Selenium File upload

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-rc

How to automate Uploading a file using `selenium`.

How to give file Path ??

My `TextBox` is Readonly. I cant type the file path directly in the `textbox`.

Also, how to stop the selinum server until that file completely uploaded.??

My File upload field is a invisible field. And i found its code using firebug add on.

Before adding a file code is like this.

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AsyncfileUpload_ClientState" type="hidden" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AsyncfileUpload_ClientState" autocomplete="off" value="{'isEnabled':'true','uploadedFiles':[]}">
```

And after adding a file(doc file). The code changed to

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AsyncfileUpload_ClientState" type="hidden" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AsyncfileUpload_ClientState" autocomplete="off" value="{'isEnabled':'true','uploadedFiles':[{"fileInfo":{"FileName":"scope.docx","ContentType":"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document","ContentLength":12887},"metaData":"/wEFsAF7IlRlbXBGaWxlTmFtZSI6ImZyeWd1NGNqLmt1YSIsIkFzeW5jVXBsb2FkVHlwZU5hbWUiOiJUZWxlcmlrLldlYi5VSS5VcGxvYWRlZEZpbGVJbmZvLCBUZWxlcmlrLldlYi5VSSwgVmVyc2lvbj0yMDExLjEuNTE5LjM1LCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPTEyMWZhZTc4MTY1YmEzZDQiffOraDjiYXPavAAMYOUAVVhGEKk8"}]}">
```

What is the Xpath here?

I tried with xpath id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AsyncfileUpload_ClientState". The code which i used is

`selenium.type("id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AsyncfileUpload_ClientState","c:\\docfile1.doc");`

But its not working.

Help Me..

Comment: I _think_ it won't work, since the `input` is `type=hidden`. The selenium file uploading feature works only on visible `input`s with `type=file`. How do you upload the file as a human being, what do you have to do?

Comment: Clicking on that upload field opens a dialogue box(window). then i have to chose the file. Once check this link(http://www.testrepublic.com/group/seleniumusers/forum/topics/how-to-upload-a-file-using-1) which is same as my Question..   Check the second reply there.

Comment: Why is it hidden? In the screenshot I could see the text box. Which version of selenium are you using? 1.0 or webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression for this `input` would be `//input[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AsyncfileUpload_ClientState']`.

However, I fear this won't work since Selenium usually refuses to work with invisible elements. Also, `hidden <inputs>` are usually just containers for pre-filled data or containers for script-validated-and-edited data.

You should be looking for a `<input type='file' />` if there's some, or maybe a javascript handling the click on the enclosing element (but, frankly, that's usually not the case - the scripts tend to act on edit of the input, not on the click on them).

If you can't find it, post some more code. The best thing would be a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), so take the source of the page and make it naked, strip everything unnecessary for us from it. We love code. And we love anything that's naked.

And about the wait for the upload to be complete: There's no such default thing. If the file is sent during a usual form upload (by clicking the Submit button), then the browser will wait. If it is uploaded immediately, you'll have to wait smartly. Realize what changes after a successful upload, then wait for that element/message to appear. With Selenium 2 (WebDriver), this [can be done](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) very [easily](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Wait.html).

Comment: Every `AsyncfileUpload` field I googled is pointing me to [ASP.net AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) or some derivative - all of which use the normal and predicted `<input type="file">` field. Your best hope now is to ask the developer of the page (I assume it's your colleague) to make something about it, or at least give you some advice. Or contact MS support for [ASP.net AJAX](http://forums.asp.net/) / [Silverlight](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?ln=en&prid=11322&gsaid=528185&st=1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
selenium.type("xpath of text box","path of your file")
```

OR for IDE

```
command=type
target=xpath_of_text_box
value=Path_of_your_file
```

example:

```
selenium.type("id=cvfile", "D:\\Automation\\resume.doc");
```